# How to set form control value in nested form

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular7

```
this.workScheduleTableForm =this.fb.group({
  rowId:[''],
  personId:[''],
  permanentWorkSchedule:[''],
  workScheduleDayDetails:this.fb.group({
     days:[''],
    sun:this.fb.group({
      hr:[''],
      code:[''],
      start:[''],
      end:[''],
      lunch:[''],
    }),
  }),
})
```

I am able to set second level like

```
this.workScheduleTableForm.controls.workScheduleDayDetails['controls']['days'].setValue('test')
```

problem with third level

```
this.workScheduleTableForm.controls.workScheduleDayDetails.control.days.['control']['hr'].setValue('test');
```

I try this one but its not working.

Comment: this.workScheduleTableForm.controls.workScheduleDayDetails['controls']['days'].setValue('test');

Comment: please explain me for third level . how i will set value for hr:['']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work the same way it works for second level. Please note that you have written `control` instead of `controls` in the code for third level.

`this.workScheduleTableForm.get('workScheduleDayDetails').get('sun').get('hr').setValue('value');`

OR

`this.workScheduleTableForm.controls.workScheduleDayDetails.controls.sun.controls['hr'].setValue('value');`